# What is the source of this famous verse?

Tags: shloka, identification-request

> आकाशात् पतितं तोयं यथा गच्छति सागरम् ।
>   सर्वदेवनमस्कारं केशवं प्रतिगच्छति ॥
>
> ākāśāt patitaṃ toyaṃ yathā gacchati sāgaram ।
>   sarvadevanamaskāraṃ keśavaṃ pratigacchati ॥
>
> **Meaning**:
>
> As the water that falls down in rain from anywhere in the sky finally reaches the Ocean, the worship of any divine aspect ultimately reaches the Supreme Being.

The above verse is quite famous. This shloka is used by many to prove the oneness of the God.

- From which scripture is the above verse taken?
- If the verse is not one from any veda or upanishad, then who is the author of it?

<sup>Translation from [this](http://www.speakingtree.in/blog/aakashath-pathitham-thoyam-yatha-gachathi-sagaram-sarvadeva) blog</sup>

Comment: I think a Vaishanava Purana contains this verse as it says "keśavaṃ pratigacchati".

Comment: Both [this](http://www.mahapashupatastra.com/2011/09/offerings-made-to-krishna-actually-goes.html) & [this](http://www.advaita-vedanta.in/adi-sankara-jagadguru) site say that the sloka is from some Subhasitas..

Comment: @Rickross That's the reason I have added the second bullet point.

Comment: A similar verse is in Skandha Purana "यथा तोयप्रवाहाणां समुद्र: परमावधि । तथैव सर्व मार्गाणां साक्षान्निष्ठा महेश्वरः ।। As all streams ultimately empty themselves into the ocean, so all these paths ultimately lead to the Great Lord Himself."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The śloka appears to be from the end of [Viṣṇusahasranāma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishnu_sahasranama) belonging to a [recension](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/1_sanskr/2_epic/mbh/mbh_13_u.htm) of the Mahābhārata that did not make it to the [BORI critical edition](http://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/txt/mbh13.itx):

> 13,135.142d*0637_06   rudra uvāca
>
> 13,135.142d*0637_07   rāma rāmeti rāmeti rame rāme manorame 
>   13,135.142d*0637_08   śrīsahasranāmatattulyaṃ rāmanāma varānane
>
> 13,135.142d*0638_01   iti stutvā hṛṣīkeśaṃ pārthas tūṣṇīṃ sthitas tataḥ 
>   13,135.142d*0639_01   namo brahmaṇyadevāya gobrāhmaṇahitāya ca 
>   13,135.142d*0639_02   jagaddhitāya kṛṣṇāya govindāya namo namaḥ
>
> 13,135.142d*0639_03   **ākāśāt patitaṃ toyaṃ yathā gacchati sāgaram** 
>   13,135.142d*0639_04   **sarvadevanamaskāraḥ keśavaṃ prati gacchati**
>
> 13,135.142d*0639_05   sarvavedeṣu yat puṇyaṃ sarvavedeṣu yat phalam 
>   13,135.142d*0639_06   tat phalaṃ puruṣa āpnoti stutvā devaṃ janārdanam
>
> 13,135.142d*0640_01   jitaṃ te puṇḍarīkākṣa namas te viśvabhāvana 
>   13,135.142d*0640_02   namas te 'stu hṛṣīkeśa mahāpuruṣapūrvaja

[This](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/820/2995) question states that a slightly different version of Viṣṇusahasranāma is also part of Padma and Skanda Purāṇas but I didn't find the śloka in those.

Comment: Can you  tell from where you quoted ? I can't find it.

Comment: See [here](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/1_sanskr/2_epic/mbh/mbh_13_u.htm) on GRETIL website.