# What is the source of "śāntākāraṃ bhujagaśayanaṃ padmanābhaṃ sureśaṃ" sloka of Lord Vishnu?

Tags: scripture, vishnu, prayer, resource

> शान्ताकारं भुजगशयनं पद्मनाभं सुरेशं
>
> विश्वाधारं गगनसदृशं मेघवर्ण शुभाङ्गम् ।
>
> लक्ष्मीकान्तं कमलनयनं योगिभिर्ध्यानगम्यम्
>
> वन्दे विष्णुं भवभयहरं सर्वलोकैकनाथम् ॥
>
> śāntākāraṃ bhujagaśayanaṃ padmanābhaṃ sureśaṃ
>
> viśvādhāraṃ gaganasadṛśaṃ meghavarṇa śubhāṅgam ।
>
> lakṣmīkāntaṃ kamalanayanaṃ yogibhirdhyānagamyam
>
> vande viṣṇuṃ bhavabhayaharaṃ sarvalokaikanātham ॥

Above is a beautiful shloka written in the prayer of Lord Vishnu. I thought it was in Shri Ramcharitmanas and Shri Tulsidas ji was the author of this shloka but I was wrong. Please tell me the source of this shloka.

Comment: It is Dhayana Sloka of Vishnu Sahasranamam. But i don't know which scripture has that sloka.

Comment: It's not found in the Mahabharata, but it may be found in some Puranas.

Comment: @user411518 I have already given two links in my answer itself..Of which the Kamakoti is an authority..Here is another site which is also a good site for Hinduism..It also mentions the verses in ur Q as a part of the Dhyana Sloka of VS that's found in MB..[Hindupedia](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Vishnu_Sahasranamam)..Given the way our scriptures are handed down from generations it is not that easy to come to any conclusions by personally verifying one or two manuscripts that r available..That's why we have to rely on experts whom we consider as authority..

Comment: @user411518 Also in many cases a Sloka or a Mantra is found in more than one scriptures ..So don't be surprised if the same verses are found in Puranas or other Shastras..I personally know few Slokas/Mantras like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three Sahsranama stotrams dedicated to Lord Vishnu are found in Padma Purana,Skanda Purana and the Mahabharata.They are together called the "Trividha Vishnu Sahasranamams".Similarly,for Shiva we have "Chaturvidha Sahsranamams" but from Agama Texts we have many more.

Anyways,the verse in question appears within the Dhyana Sloka of the Vishnu Sahasranama that is from the [Anushasanika Parva](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/articles/mahabharata2.html) of Mahabharata.

Also, as you  can see from the passage given below, that Vyasa is mentioned as the Rishi of the stotram so **Vyasa only is the author of those verses.**

> Asya Shri Vishnordivya Sahasra naama Stotra Maha Mantrasya **Shri Veda
>   Vyaaso Bhagavan Rishih** Anushtup Chhandah Shri Maha Vishnuh Paramatmaa
>   Shrimannarayano Devata Amritaamshad –bhavo Bhanuriti beejam, Devaki
>   nandanassrashteti Shaktih,Udbhavah Kshobhano Deva iti paramo Mantrah
>   Shankha bhrinnandakeecha Chakriti keelakam, Sharangadhanvaa Gadaa
>   dhara ithystram Rathaanga paani rakshobhya iti netram, Trisaamaa
>   saamagassaameti kavacham, Aanandam Parabrahmeti yonih,
>   Rithussudarshanah Kaala iti digbandhah Vishwarupa itidhyanam Shri Maha
>   Vishnu preetyarthey kainkaryarupey Shri Vishnu Sahasra naama japey
>   viniyogah......
>
> ---
>
> Dhyaanam: Ksheerodanvatpradeshe Shuchimani Vilasatsaikatey
>   Mouktikaanaam, Maalaaklaptaa –sanasthah Sphatika Mani nibhair
>   mouktikair manditaangaha/ Shubhrabhrairadabhrairupari virachitairmukta
>   peeyusha varshaih, Anandeenah puneeyaadari naleenagadaa shankha
>   paanirmukundah/ Bhu paadasya naabhirviyadadasrura nilaschandra
>   Suryoucha Netrey, Karnaavaashaashiro Dyormukhamkapi dakanoyasya
>   vaasyamdbhih/ Antastham yasya Vishwam Sura nara khaga Gobhogi
>   Gandharvadaityaschitramram Ramyate tam Tribhuvana vapusham Vishnu
>   meesham Namaami/ **Shantaakaaram Bhujagashayanam Padmanaabham
>   Suresham, Vishwaakaaram Gagana sadrusham Meghavarnam Shubhangam/
>   Lakshmi kaantam Kamala nayanam Yogi hriddhyaana gamyam, Vandey Vishnum
>   Bhavabhayaharam Sarva Lokaika naatham/** Meghashyaamam Peetakousheya
>   vaasam Shri Vatsaangkam Koustubhodbhaasitangam,Punyopetam
>   Pundarikayataaksham Vishnum vandey Sarva Lokaika naatham/ Sashankha
>   chakram Sakireeta kundalam Sapeeta Vastram Saraseeruhekshanam, Sahaara
>   Vakshahsthala Koustubham Namaami Vishnum Shirasaa Chaturbhujam/ Harih
>   Om/

**Meaning**

> May Bhagavan Mukunda purify us as he is seated on the Ocean of Milk in
>   the surroundings of sand that reflects the illumination of precious
>   gems while wearing garlands of pearls transparent like crystals and
>   adorned with Gada-Shankha-Chakra-Padma besides smiles of blissful
>   trance showering rains of nectar from pure clouds over head on the
>   blue skies; I salute Vishnu with admiration and deep veneration as He
>   his physique representing the Three Worlds apppears as though Earth is
>   His Sacred Feet, Sky His Navel, Air as His breathing, Sun and Moon as
>   His eyes, Dishas or Directions as His ears, Heaven as His head, Fire
>   as His Countenance and Oceans as His stomach. I salute Vishnu who
>   contains the Universe in totality with Devas, humanity, birds, cattle,
>   snakes, Gandharvas, Demons and so on all of whom  act and play in
>   their own ways and means. I salute to and prostrate before Vishnu who
>   is the Paramount Power  in all the Lokas as He is the embodiment of
>   Peace and Tranquility resting comfortably on Sesha Naaga as Padmanabha
>   or with a Lotus sprouted from his naabhi, Suresha or the Over Lord of
>   Sura Ganas, Vishwaakaaram or the Divine Profile of Vishwa or the
>   Universe, Gagana Sadrusham or like the most undefinable Skies, Neela
>   Varnam or of Blue complexion and Shubhangam or of the most auspicious
>   Physical Frame; Lakshmi Kantam or the family partner of Devi Lakshmi;
>   Kamala nayanam or of the enticing eyes of Lotus; Yogi hriddhyaana
>   gamyam or the Ultimate Goal of the heart-felt meditation of Yogis;
>   Bhavabhayaharam or the Single Saviour of the Dread and Distress of
>   Life’s Travails and the Unique Chief of all the Lokas; Bhagavan is
>   also renowned for His Physique of Cloud-like Blue Complexion, His
>   abode as the Ocean of Milk or dressed in yellow robes, Shri Vatsa mole
>   on his Chest,  the bright Koustubha Mani on his body, Punyopetam or
>   surrounded by devotees and Dharmaatmas and of Lotus Eyes. Bhagavan is
>   famed as the ever-adorned with Shankha-Chakra-Kireeta-Kundala-Yellow
>   robes, Lotus like vision, Sacred and glitttering neck laces on chest
>   and the outstanding Koustubha all decorated on his Four Mighty Hands!
>   Indeed to that unparalleled Bhagavan Vishnu, my sincere salutations
>   and Prayers

[Here](http://sanskrit.safire.com/pdf/VISHNU_TRANS.PDF) is another link for the Vishnu Sahsranama Stotram from Mahabharata:

You can read the Dhyanam part from page 3 onwards  and on page 5 we get the verses in your questions:

> [image]

I'm unable to copy sanskrit verses from that document hence given the image as a reference.

Comment: I don't think Dhyana Slokas are part of the Mahabharata.

Comment: @Sv Oh ..did u read MB in sanskrit?There are many stotrams kavachmas dedicated to the Navagrahas that are part of the MB..I have read them..at the end they say.."Thus ends the Rahu kavachm which is in Dhritarashtra Jayanta Samvade etc etc..and such kavachams have Dhyana and viniyogah at the beginning...Any sahasranama stotrams have Viniyoga,Anga-Kara nyasa and Dhyana..

Comment: You can read Sanskrit MB in my answer [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16769/2995). You can search for VSS  slokha # from my answer and then go to the beginning. Don't think you'll find this particular Dhyana Sloka there. So not sure. Could be a sampradaya thing which originated later.

Comment: @sv I don't need to verify personally..I given links from authoritative Hindu sites only..and i haven't read MB in sanskrit myself..also See [Rahu Kavacham](http://sanskrit.safire.com/pdf/RAHU_KAVACHAM_TRANS.pdf)..at the end it says "Thus ends the Rahu Kavcham which is from Drona Parva and which is from the dialogue of Dhritarashtra and Sanjaya".. ..and for this kavacham the Dhyanam is given at the very beginning viz-"Pranamami sada rahum surpakaram Kiritanam..."

Comment: Sorry Sanjaya and not Jayanta in my first comment above ;D..BTW,Kamakoti is an authority..so once i have used that site as a reference i don't need to cross check ..

Comment: @sv. Is right, the Shantakaram Shloka is not present in the Anushasana Parva.  It is true that when people chant the version of the Sahasranamam found in the Mahahbharata, it is customary to recite the Shantakaram Shloka, but it is not actually present in the text.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Well none of u and sv are experts..so i don't have any reasons to believe in what u say as true..As i have said already since i have given Kamakoti as my reference ,which is an authority on hinduism,i don't have any need to cross-check whether the content they provided is true or false..If some one thinks my answer is wrong then pls down-vote and move on..

Comment: I am not saying that the Kamakoti website is wrong.  They are providing the Anushasana Parva's version of the Sahasranamam along with the verses that are customarily recited along with it.  They do not claim that very single verse in that webpage is from the actual text of the Anushasana Parva.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan The linked page starts with -(Maha Bharata –Anushasanika Parva)  and ends with ":Iti Shri Maha Bharatey Shata Sahasrikaayaam Samhitaayaam Vaiyaasikyaa Manushaasana Parva -antargata Anushasanika Parvani Moksha Dharmey Bheeshma Yudhishtara Samvaadey Shri Vishnor -divya Sahasra naama Stotram Naamaikona Panchaashataadhika Shatatamodhyaayah" So how much more explicit they have to be to prove that they r actually quoting from MB?..And i don't think their target audience is sceptics either..

Comment: " The three Sahsranama stotrams dedicated to Lord Vishnu are found in Padma Purana,Skanda Purana and the Mahabharata.They are together called the "Trividha Vishnu Sahasranamams" " Why only these three?  Aren't there any other Vishnu Sahasranama stotras? There is another stotra in Garuda purana also.